# Why is "Object" possible undefined?

Tags: typescript

Can anyone please explain to me why typescript is throwing an error here:

```
let a: number | undefined; 

let b = [2,3,4,5,6];

for (let c of b) {

    a = 3;

    if (!a) {
        continue;
    }

    b.filter(x => +x !== +a);

}
```

[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwgHwo%20AJiAGYCW8IBA3BAFC2iSoQC8EA2gEwA0AzNwBZuAVm4A2ALpV6xAPZYAFIwgBjCLOIRUASggBvehCPRWEXtNrGIpTQoCEUXQatWVs%20GHKIQ0qwF9DY1QAOjJgMEwFAA9WAD4IAGoYuxY2BMcLAMCgA)

Comment: It's essentially a design limitation of TS. TS has no way to represent that `filter()` calls its callback immediately, and the narrowing done on the type of `a` does not therefore propagate down into the callback body.  See [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for more information about the issue. The workaround here is to copy your narrowed value to a `const` so that TS knows its type is narrow for all time; shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mMB9zW).

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for your comment. If you copy this to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a general limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a full discussion.

When you take the variable `a` of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `number | undefined` and [assign](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) a `number` to it (`a = 3`), or do a [truthiness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing) check on it (`if (!a) continue`), the type checker [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) its apparent type to just `number`, after which you can treat it like a `number`:

```
a = 3;
if (!a) { continue; }
a.toFixed(2); // okay
```

Unfortunately, the effects of narrowing do not cross function boundaries.  Inside the callback `x => +x !== +a` that you pass to `b.filter()`, the type of `a` is stubbornly `number | undefined` instead of just `number`, and the compiler considers `+a` on a possibly-`undefined` `a` to be a programmer mistake.

The reason the compiler does not know that `a` is a `number` inside the callback is because it doesn't know when the callback will be run, or even *if* it will be run. Because of the way closures work, it is possible, at least syntactically, for `a` to be `undefined` when the callback runs:

```
for (let c of b) {
    a = 3;
    if (!a) { continue; }
    a.toFixed(2); // okay
    someRandomFunction(x => +x !== +a);
}
a = undefined; // maybe
```

You know `a` is definitely a `number` when you call `someRandomFunction`, but for all you know, `someRandomFunction` waits for an hour and then calls the callback, by which time `a` has been set back to `undefined` by some later statement.  The type system has no way to mark that a function will call its callback parameter immediately, so [the `filter()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might as well be `someRandomFunction`.  Oh well.

---

Maybe it would be possible for the compiler to detect that for the entire lifetime of `a` it never goes back to `undefined`, but that would be hard to make performant.  Or maybe it would be possible to introduce an `immediate` annotation to the language so that `filter()` could be seen as "safe"... and in fact there is an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#11498](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498), but for now it's not implemented.

For now, there are only workarounds.  By far the easiest one is to take the narrowed expression and assign it to a new `const`, and then use the `const` inside the callback:

```
const _a = a; // number
b.filter(x => +x !== +_a); // okay
```

Since `a` is narrowed to `number` at that point, when you write `const _a = a`, the compiler infers `_a` to be of type `number`, not `number | undefined`.  There is no need to narrow `_a`; it is always and forever `number` in any scope in which it exists.  So the callback `x => +x !== +a` compiles without error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwgHwo+AJiAGYCW8IBA3AFA2iSoQC8EA2gEwA0EAzDwBYeAVh4A2ALq0axAPZYAFAwgBjCLOIRUASggBvOhCPQWfWsYilNCgIRRde1bPhhyiEFQgBfGhagA6MFkAMVIAD0oFDm1PAHpY9QBrKABPX2MVZwBnSAB9KFMoOISkNEx0o1R-MmAwTAUwlgA+CABqRptmVlb8mIh4pNS6HzoC1nwiMgpqfoTkVPQgA)